# How to store a datatable in a session and retrieve it

Tags: c#, .net, session

How can I store a datatable in a Session and retrieve the values from the Session in C#/.NET?

Comment: Session["BufferDatatable"] = dt;

 ((DataTable)Session["BufferDatatable"]).Rows.Add(titlelbl.Text, txtEnable.Text, txtValue.Text, txtValue.Text);

solved the problem

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add a datatable into session:

```
DataTable Tissues = new DataTable();

Tissues = dal.returnTissues("TestID", "TestValue");// returnTissues("","") sample     function for adding values


Session.Add("Tissues", Tissues);
```

Retrive that datatable from session:

```
DataTable Tissues = Session["Tissues"] as DataTable
```

or

```
DataTable Tissues = (DataTable)Session["Tissues"];
```

Comment: I think this will affect the performance of the application/page if, for example, the datatable contains 10,000 records.

Comment: @Musikero31 Depending on how you use it, it could improve the performance of the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

To store `DataTable` in Session:

```
DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
Session["dtTest"] = dtTest;
```

To retrieve `DataTable` from Session:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable) Session["dtTest"];
```

Comment: What does this add to the accepted answer by amexn in 2010, 6 years prior?

Comment: Nothing, it appears. It should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that but storing a DataSet object in Session is not very efficient. If you have a web app with lots of users it will clog your server memory really fast.

If you really must do it like that I suggest removing it from the session as soon as you don't need the DataSet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is _how_ to store a datatable in session. It should be a comment or deleted altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Generally what you want to do is keep size on the Session and ViewState small. I generally just store IDs and small amounts of packets in Session and ViewState.

For instance if you want to pass large chunks of data from one page to another, you can store an ID in the querystring and use that ID to either get data from a database or a file.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question OP asked, which is "how to do it".

Answer (score 0):

```
// DECLARATION
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
DataTable dt_ShoppingBasket = context.Session["Shopping_Basket"] as DataTable;

// TRY TO ADD rows with the info into the DataTable
try
{
    // Add new Serial Code into DataTable dt_ShoppingBasket
    dt_ShoppingBasket.Rows.Add(new_SerialCode.ToString());

    // Assigns new DataTable to Session["Shopping_Basket"]
    context.Session["Shopping_Basket"] = dt_ShoppingBasket;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // IF FAIL (EMPTY OR DOESN'T EXIST) - 
    // Create new Instance, 
    DataTable dt_ShoppingBasket= new DataTable();

    // Add column and Row with the info
    dt_ShoppingBasket.Columns.Add("Serial");
    dt_ShoppingBasket.Rows.Add(new_SerialCode.ToString());

    // Assigns new DataTable to Session["Shopping_Basket"]
    context.Session["Shopping_Basket"] = dt_PanierCommande;
}



// PRINT TESTS
DataTable dt_To_Print = context.Session["Shopping_Basket"] as DataTable;

foreach (DataRow row in dt_To_Print.Rows)
{
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DATATABLE IN SESSION: " + item);
    }
}
```