# Holding on to data passed from page to page - WP7 and C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, navigation

I'm creating a WP7 application using C#, and I require to pass data from one page to the other.

I found solutions on SO, but I'm still running into problems.

On 'Page 1', I wish to display a list, that can be populated by the user, using input from 'Page 2'.

I used the following statement in 'Page 2' while navigating back to 'Page 1':  `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?text="+WhoBox.Text, UriKind.Relative));`
`WhoBox` is a Text Box.

On 'Page 1', I have the following:
`protected override void OnNavigateTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)`
`{`
`base.OnNavigatedTo(e);`
`if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("text"))`
                `ListBlock.Text = ListBlock.Text + NavigationContext.QueryString["text"];`
`}`

Now, this works, but in a limited fashion. If I try adding something from 'Page 2' for a second time, it replaces what is present in `ListBlock` (which is a Text Block) with the newly added text instead of appending it.

Shouldn't `ListBlock.Text = ListBlock.Text + NavigationContext.QueryString["text"];` cause the new text to be appended, rather than to entirely replace the older text?

**EDIT: I may have found the solution.** For whatever reason, no changes in the XAML or .cs file are reflected when I run the program using F5. Am I doing something wrong? For example, even if I delete a button, it still appears when I Debug (F5) the program. Is there some setting I need to change? Or am I supposed to use some other command? I'm relatively new to Visual Studio, so please excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using sessions and datatable: [Storing and retrieving datatable from session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288299/storing-and-retrieving-datatable-from-session)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the moment you again leave your page 1 it is basically disposed of. Meaning any text that was set in the Listbox is also removed. You will , in other words, need to save the state of that page before leaving it.

There several possibilites here:

- Use AppSettings  (see [Windows phone 7 config / appSettings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145803/windows-phone-7-config-appsettings) )
- Write the state to a local database
- Do a quick'n dirty fix by saving the Text in the App.xaml.cs which all pages can work with: First you need to create the application-wide variable (and initialize if needed) inside the app.xaml.cs file. For example:

  ```
  public partial class App : Application
  {     public string myText;
  ```

From now on you can reach any App-variable through the Application.Current object. So if you need to access bigVar from some page in you application (e.g. MainPage) you simply type:

```
string Text = (Application.Current as App).myText;
```