# Save data records and use it again without querying again into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a two control, which are a Search button and Export button. The user will 'Search' the data and the data will be inserted into DataTable and bound to the GridView or Repeater, and then when user click Export, the DataTable will be passed into the class that will generate an Excel file using the data inside DataTable.

In my current code, the Search button and Export button both will query to fetch data from database. But what I need is only Search button that will query, and store the data into a DataTable or something, and when Export button is clicked it will use the earlier data to generate the Excel file.

Here is my current code:
Report.aspx

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</body>
```

Report.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Page load */
        }

protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = GetData();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

protected DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        /* Query operation */
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }

protected void btn_export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var excelClass = new ExcelClass();
        excelClass.ExcelData = GetData();
    }
```

I attempt to create a DataTable as a property in 'Report.aspx.cs' and fill it with the data when Search is clicked. But when I Export , the DataTable is empty again.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Page load */
        }

protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetData();
            GridView1.DataSource = dataTable ;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

protected void GetData()
    {
        /* Query operation */
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }

protected void btn_export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var excelClass = new ExcelClass();
        excelClass.ExcelData = dataTable;
    }
```

But, I need to fetch the data just once, when Search is clicked, and use the data again when I Export it, so it wont query to the database twice.

Comment: Every time you do a postback you're dealing with a new instance of your page class. That means a new datatable object as well.If you really want to persist it between postbacks then you can put the datatable in the Session, ViewState, or other location that persists state. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288299/storing-and-retrieving-datatable-from-session to use datatable in session.

Comment: Agree with @ManojNaik. But keeping lot of data on viewstate will make your page "Bulkier" and affects the overall page response time during postbacks.

Comment: Yeah, I consider of using viewstate and session too, but that will affect the performance of my page, because the data is massive, it can be up to 600k to 800k records. I just got a reference of using caching method, but still researching of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6831665/3883460 may help you out.

Comment: Why not make a second call to the database and keep the web app small?

Comment: Thanks @RojalinSahoo :)

Comment: @Alexander you got the point. Thanks. So, I've given some Views and have to generate reports based on those Views. I'm not authorized to alter anything in the database. Unfortunately some of the View's query performance is slow. Because of it I want to limit my app from querying to database. But after some research and consideration, from all methods like ViewState, Session, and even Caching none of it is efficient to handle large amount of data, so I have to contact the person who write the Views and ask him to fix it xD

Comment: My Solution may be applied here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288299/storing-and-retrieving-datatable-from-session/56442018#56442018

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways you can achieve this as mentioned below.

> 1. Using Session

You can use session for this but this will affect the performance of the application/page if, for example, the dataTable contains 10,000 records.

Add a dataTable into session:

```
DataTable dataTable= new DataTable();

dataTable= GetData();

Session.Add("dataTable", dataTable);
```

Retrive that datatable from session:

```
DataTable dataTable = Session["dataTable"] as DataTable
```

or

```
DataTable dataTable= (DataTable)Session["dataTable"];
```

> 2. Export a GridView1.DataSource to a dataTable

```
DataTable dataTable= Gridview1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

> 3. Iterate each Row from GridView to DataTable

```
//Create a new DataTable.
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

//Add columns to DataTable.
foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
}

//Loop through the GridView and copy rows.
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        dataTable.Rows[row.RowIndex][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess it would cost the performance of my page, because the data can be up to 600k-800k records. Thanks anw.

Comment: @grayfield Please review the answer, with three different ways you can achieve this. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Many thanks Charan. Sorry, my code in the above is just a general depiction of my program. Actually I create two DataTable, one for the displaying with just a chunk of all data, used for the GridView, and one for containing all the data and used to generate the Excel. Because if I bind all the data to the GridView (600-800k records) the DOM will be overwhelmed, I think. Sorry if my post is confusing, I'll edit it. But thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.